# squid blacklist solution

Tags: blacklist, squid

I've installed squid proxy server for a company and now they ask me to add blacklisting capabilities for squid.

The most obvious thing that comes to mind is just to find a huge blacklist file on the internet and hook it up to squid configuration as external file.

The other option is to use dedicated solution like squidguard.

I also want to include ability to edit and add entries to a black list through web interface. Although it's not strictly necessarily since I can write it myself with php.

I would welcome any suggestions. My main priority is performance and reliability and if possible I'd like to keep it simple.

Comment: This question was answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762189/blacklist-ip-database

Answer (score 2):

It's been quite some time since I've done this. However I worked at a religious boarding school for a while, and they liked to block everything.

I've been looking for the same feed, however I can't seem to find it. The way I did it was to find a list that was maintained on the net, and I wrote a simple bash script to curl the list, echo it out into the appropriate list, and then restart squid.

Simple, I realize, and unless you're an employee there all the time, it might be untenable. Hope the idea helps, but I'm pretty sure you are on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know of a web interface to manage squid blacklists, but you may want to look at [DansGuarding](http://dansguardian.org/). It has a very good blacklist and can be edited to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a cheap or free solution, the huge blacklist as Squid ACL is a valid option.

However, if you are *seriously* concerned about blocking access to some categories of web content, one needs a solution that also blocks all proxies (filter circumventors) and has a URL database with few errors.  There are various professional solutions ranging from cheap to expensive.

You mentioned squidguard, but ufdbGuard development went on where squidguard stopped 5 years ago.  BEsides the classic URL filtering, ufdbGuard also detects SSH tunnels, VPNs and other solutions that try to circumvent a URL filter.  ufdbGuard has the same configuration syntax as squidGuard and is Open Source Software.  You can download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/ufdbguard/ or [www.urlfilterdb.com](http://www.urlfilterdb.com).
ufdbGuard works with both free and commercial databases.

Answer (score 0):

Use squid and a blacklist like https://oisd.nl/

Squid ACL example:

```
acl myblacklist dstdomain "/path_to/myblacklist"
http_access deny myblacklist
```